# n-gram implementaion in spring-boot ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to achieve autocomplete in elasticsearch, I am using it inside spring boot, I have tried a lot and tried with many example from internet but not able to make it. below is my code example pls help me on this.

Main Class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNatsAnnotations
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ElasticsearchProperties.class)
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "com.text.model"
})
@ComponentScan(
        {
                "com.text.elastic",
                "com.text.elastic.controller",
                "com.text.elastic.service",
                "com.text.elastic.service.impl",
                "com.text.nats.utils"
        }
)
public class ElasticServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ElasticServicesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Bean Class:-

```
@Setting(settingPath = "elasticsearch-settings.json")
@Document(indexName = "content", type = "content", shards = 1, replicas = 0, createIndex = true,   refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Content {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Locale locale;

   // @Field(type = text, index = true, store = true, analyzer = "standard")
    @Field(
            type = FieldType.String,
            index = FieldIndex.analyzed,
            searchAnalyzer = "standard",
            //indexAnalyzer = "type_ahead",
            analyzer = "standard"

            /*,
            store = true*/
    )
    private String contentTitle;
```

Here I want to achieve it in contentTitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mapping

Concise way of using annotation:

```
@CompletionField()
private Completion suggest;
```

Or more powerful but tedious way:

```
{
    "content" : {
        "properties" : {
            "contentTitle" : { "type" : "string" },
            "suggest" : { "type" : "completion",
                "analyzer" : "simple",
                "search_analyzer" : "simple"
            }
        }
    }
}


//Then refer to the mapping by `@Mapping`:
@Setting(settingPath = "elasticsearch-settings.json")
@Document(indexName = "content", type = "content", shards = 1, replicas = 0, createIndex = true,   refreshInterval = "-1")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/content-mapping.json")
public class Content {...}
```

#### Index

We can index as our common entity:

```
esTemplate.save(new File(...));
```

#### Query

The `ElasticsearchTemplate` has the method for query suggest:

```
public SuggestResponse suggest(SuggestBuilder.SuggestionBuilder<?> suggestion, String... indices);
```

#### Ref

- [Blog posts about completion](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/07/elasticsearch-problem-lists2-with-spring.html#completion)
- [Official document about completion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-suggesters-completion.html)